# Play 2 Configuration Substitution not working

Tags: scala, playframework, configuration, config, typesafe

I'm not very familiar with play but working on an application whereby the properties are loaded via a **.properties** file and a variable is passed through the command line.

E.g.

Note this is a play 2.2.3 app

```
play -Dhost=app123 -Dconfig.file=app.properties run
```

In the properties file:

```
app.host=${host}
```

When I check the configuration loaded at runtime using

```
Play.configuration
```

or

```
ConfigFactory.load
```

The substitution for **app.host** does not seem to work - the property is evaluated to **${host}** as the literal String (instead of **app123**).

Is there something that needs to be set for substitution to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines of the documentation and code of both [Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Configuration) and the [Typesafe Config library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config), using a file with a `.properties` extension may preclude substitution from environment variables and/or system properties.

I was able to get your use case to work using a file called `application.conf` on my Play 2.4 app.

It may well be as simple as renaming your file to `app.conf` - the format of a standard `.properties` file is actually valid [HOCON](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#using-hocon-the-json-superset), and HOCON is what you need to get property substitution.